# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.7, jupyter

No acabo de entender, cómo superar este error. En diversos scripts publicados en Internet, encuentro sentencias, para la creación de columnas en un DataFrame, similares a la que a mi me da el error mencionado en el título. Esta es una adaptación de una de ellas.

```
# Consulta StackOverflow
import pandas as pd
from math import floor
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

# Importar cotizaciones
ticker = "GOOG"
start = "2020-1-2"
end = "2021-4-28"
nom_val = "GOOG"
df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
df.rename(columns={'High': 'high',  'Low': 'low', 'Open':'open', 
                      'Close':nom_val, 'Volume':'volume', 'Adj Close':'adj close'}, inplace=True)
datos = df[[nom_val]]
datos['Log return'] = 0
datos['Return']  = 0

datos
```

Me devuelve el error:

[image: imágen del error]

Realizo la siguiente modificación de código:

```
datos1 = df[[nom_val]]
datos1.loc[:, 'Log return']  = 0
datos1.loc[:, 'Return']  = 0

datos1
```

Me devuelve:

[image: imágen del error 2]

En ambos casos, las columnas se crean bien.

¿Cómo puedo evitar este error?. Agradeceré me aclaren los conceptos relacionados .

Comment: La solución más sencilla, en este caso, ha sido hacer una copia del DataFrame, de la siguiente manera." datos = df[[nom_val]].copy(deep=True)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos posibles soluciones son: crear un dataframe nuevo, de la siguiente manera.

```
# Definimos un dataframe nuevo
df2 = datos.loc[:, [nom_val, 'Log return','Return' ]]
df2
```

Hacer una copia del daf original:

```
datos = df[["nom_val"]].copy()
```